# Blazor server side force Desktop site when running on mobile phones

Tags: c#, android, ios, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Server site Blazor application that runs well on desktop windows. When I run it on android the whole view changes the app becomes unusable. The only to fix it is by clicking the Desktop site option on my mobile phone and then everything looks normal.

Can I force my app to run as a Desktop site only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

from Host.cshtml